# How to sort list of objects by three fields, if list is already sorted by two of them?

Tags: kotlin, collections

Lets suppose, we have `students: List<Student>` and `Student` has three fields: `schoolId`, `name`, `age`.

I need to sort this list by three fields, in SQL I would write `ORDER BY schoolId, name, age`. However, my list `students` is already sorted by `schoolId, name`. Now I need only to add sorting by third field `age` to get this list sorted by `schoolId, name, age`.

Could anyone say how to do it in kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not matter whether the list is already partially sorted or not. You should just use standard sort function:

```
val sortedStudents = students.sortedWith(compareBy(Student::schoolId, Student::name, Student::age))
```

Comment: Do I understand it right - after calling your code students list won't change, that's what you create new list. Right?

Comment: That's correct. Kotlin class `List` is immutable and can't be changed once created. You need to use `MutableList` if you want to sort in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
val sortedList = students.sortedWith(
    compareBy({ it.schoolId}, { it.name}, { it.age})
)
```